# Daily statistics using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, statistics

I have a table like this

```
 letterId      ituation             date
    1        sendtomnister        02/03/2016
    2        sendtomnister        02/03/2016
    1        sendtosignature      04/03/2016
    1        sendtosignature      04/03/2016
    2        closed               02/03/2016
```

what I want it tell me the last state of letter and for exemple how many letter closed  and how many letter sendtoMinister  ...etc

please comment I need Your feedback all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lear MySQL Query, especially the `SELECT` one.
Documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

---

For exemple, for know the number of letter `closed` you have to do the following

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableName WHERE situation = 'closed';
```

Comment: I now the basic Mysql query  but the problem that I have is  situation that change you know when I make your query SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableName WHERE situation = 'sendtoclient'; maybe the file situation it no long be  sendtoclient it become closed or other  ...so I neeed To count the letter last situation  you understand

Comment: I take example of `letterId = 1` : situation here is sendToMinister ok ? And you want the previous situation. Right ?

Comment: exactly so I want to know for exemple

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableName WHERE(last situation)  = 'closed';

Comment: It's not possible... Except if you create a column in the same table with the name `last_situation`. And each time the situation change you make this query : `UPDATE tableName SET last_situtation = situation, situation = "theNewSituation" WHERE letterId = :id`;

Comment: Or you can create an another table named for example `situation_logs` and each time the situation is update in `TableLetter` you insert in `situation_logs` a new line. Column in this table can be `id, letterID, situation, date_updated`.